# Remove bounding boxes which go outside of the image edges

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm having some trouble trying to remove bounding boxes which go beyond the image borders.

I am able to adapt the bounding boxes using *tf.clip_by_value*, to make the boxes not go beyond the edges.

```
x1 = tf.clip_by_value(boxes[:, :, 0], 0, width)
y1 = tf.clip_by_value(boxes[:, :, 1], 0, height)
x2 = tf.clip_by_value(boxes[:, :, 2], 0, width)
y2 = tf.clip_by_value(boxes[:, :, 3], 0, height)
```

But what I am actually trying, is a way to remove them, rather then clip them. Is there a function in Tensorflow which might be suitable for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone might run into the same problem in the future:

```
top_indices = tf.where(tf.math.greater(boxes[:, 1], 0))
new_boxes = tf.gather(boxes, top_indices)[:, 0, :]
bottom_indices = tf.where(tf.math.less(new_boxes[:, 3], image_size))
final_boxes = tf.gather(new_boxes, bottom_indices)[:, 0, :]
```